# I need an API that background prints PDFs in ASP.NET.WEBAPI

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api, printing, background

I'm working on a web-based KIOSK for in-house print jobs. We're a non-profit making small print publications. I've got a prototype created of portal that allows us to manage our publications (mainly PDFs), our print queues (mainly windows printers). I've been able to write C# code to use the FoxIt Reader to silently print PDFs from a RESTFUL API web service. It works. But in testing, I found serious limitations with the FoxIT Reader. Primarily, you can't specify how many copies to print, along with other basic settings. While it works, we often print in volume (50 or a hundred copies of multi-page PDFs. I could put in a loop to print the PDF N-times, but that's just ridiculous as it sends an ungodly amount of data and print jobs to the printer.

Anyways, I'm having difficulties locating a library (preferably open source) that gives me options for printing PDFs, specifiying things like # of copies, color / B&W, PRINTER MANAGES Color, etc.

I've been googling for a couple of days. I'm coming up empty. Those libraries I do come across are meant to work as WinForms foreground applications. What I need is an API that can Print PDFs as a background process (think windows service).

And just to be clear, by "Print PDF" I do not mean create a PDF. I mean take an existing PDF and sent it to a printer with options (# of copies, color/B&W, printer manages color, paper size, actual size vs. fit to paper size, orientation, etc.)

I really need some help. I'm coming up empty. Can anyone recommend an API that would help in this situation? The whole key I'm trying to avoid is FOREGROUND printing. I need to be able to spawn a print job as a background process, not interactive-user.

(My RESTFUL API web service takes an ID of a publication along with the quantity, page size, color mode (BW/Color)) and presently spawns a background print using FoxIt Reader. It does work. But without the options to specify quantity, page size, color/bw, PRINTER MANAGES Color, it's really useless for production.)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out CLPrint. You have to either call the EXE directly or just place the PDF into a directory, but you can also specify the print options like you need. You should be able to run the process as any user.

http://www.terminalworks.com/command-line-printing

http://www.terminalworks.com/command-line-printing/downloads/documentation/CLPrintGuide.pdf (Page 6 are the command line options that I believe are relevant for you)